# poor performance of fixed position elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with a fixed element on my website when scrolling when browsing with Chrome.

When scrolling up and down the page the element flickers and duplicates itself.

Usually when faced with this issue I have normally been able to resolve the issue with a simple z-index but this is not making any difference for this particular issue.

[Website Code Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elitedesignstudios/37ct87j4/)

[Actual Website](http://davidcoggins.co/) The element in question is the black scroll element on the left hand side.

[Simplified Fiddle to isolate the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/825s52kp/2/)

Here is the code from the simplified fiddle to replicate the issue:

```
// HTML

 <ul id="et-float-menu">
     <li class="et-float-menu-item1">
        <a id="scrollUp">
            <span><img /></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="et-float-menu-item2">
        <a id="scrollDown">
            <span><img /></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="jumptosection selected" id="section1">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
</div>    
<div class="jumptosection" id="section2">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
</div>    
<div class="jumptosection" id="section3">
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
</div>    
<div class="jumptosection" id="section4">
    <h2>Section 4</h2>
</div>

// JS
function changeSelection(sectionFrom, sectionTo) {
    if(sectionTo.length > 0) {
        sectionFrom.removeClass("selected");
        sectionTo.addClass("selected");
        jQuery("body").animate({scrollTop: sectionTo.offset().top});
    }
}

jQuery(document).on("click", "#scrollDown", function(){
    var currentSection = jQuery(".selected");
    var nextSection = currentSection.next(".jumptosection");

    changeSelection(currentSection, nextSection);

    return false;
});

jQuery(document).on("click", "#scrollUp", function(){
    var currentSection = jQuery(".selected");
    var prevSection = currentSection.prev(".jumptosection");

    changeSelection(currentSection, prevSection);

    return false;
});

// CSS

.jumptosection {
    height: 200px;
    background-color:#e8e8e8;
}

#et-float-menu {
position: fixed;
z-index: 11;
left: 0;
top: 45%;
background-color: #000;
padding: 20px 10px 10px 15px;
margin: 0;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
border-top-right-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}

#et-float-menu a {
padding: 0;
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 10px;
color: #fff;
}

#et-float-menu a:hover { color: #b2b2b2; transition: color 300ms ease 0s; }

#et-float-menu li {
display: block;
margin-left: 0;
}


.et-float-menu-item a { display: inline-block; font-size: 24px; position: relative; text-align: center; transition: color 300ms ease 0s; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }
.et-float-menu-item a:hover { color: #a0a0a0; }
    .et-social-icon span { display: none; }
.et-float-menu-item1 a:before { content: '↑';font-size:22px; }
.et-float-menu-item2 a:before { content: '↓';font-size:22px; }
```

Is anyone aware of the cause of this issue and a possible resolution?

Comment: I don't see this behaviour within the fiddle. What browser and version are you using?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't happen in the fiddle... that's what has me confused. This is happening in Chrome, latest version on Mac.

Comment: I don't see the behaviour in the fiddle either (latest Chrome version on Win7)

Comment: I went to your site and just saw a message saying that amazing is coming. Can't help find a problem that you can't show us.

Comment: That is just a loader that goes away after 3 seconds or so...it only happens on the site in Chrome...the scroll feature works but it slips behind different div's as you scroll. In Firefox it doesnt happen but it also doent scroll when clicked

Comment: I managed to replicate the issue in Chrome and using this [Link](http://benfrain.com/easy-css-fix-fixed-positioning-android-2-2-2-3/) I added `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the UL element and it seemed to fix the issue.. for me at least. Could you give it a try.

Comment: Indeed, I tried the fix suggested by @Scriptable and added `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to `#et-float-menu` and now I do not see the issue happening again...

Comment: @Scriptable that 100% worked! Could you please answer the question below and explain what was happening and why that worked so I can give you the Bounty...maybe +1 my question and validate that this is a real issue.

Comment: @DavidCoggins - I'd suggest you try adding some code on the question to illustrate the issue (and keep the fiddle link and the link to your site). The idea is to make the question self-sufficient so that if jsfiddle or your site goes down people can still get enough information to determine if the question/answer can help them or not

Comment: OK...ill do that now...I already renamed the question. It is sometimes hard when you have no idea where to start as I didnt in the case of this question.

Comment: @DavidCoggins Thanks, I've added the answer and another link detailing the issue below. Glad to of helped.

Comment: @Scriptable I will award the bounty once the 24 hour minimum period is up.

Comment: Thanks, thats my first one :)

Comment: what is your problem and what you want to do explain me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to replicate the issue in Chrome and using this [Link](http://benfrain.com/easy-css-fix-fixed-positioning-android-2-2-2-3/) I added `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the UL element and it seemed to fix the issue.. for me at least. Could you give it a try.

A good explanation of the issue can be found on the above link and a more in-depth review of the problem can be found [Here](http://benfrain.com/improving-css-performance-fixed-position-elements/)

Excerpt from above link http://benfrain.com/improving-css-performance-fixed-position-elements/:

> ...adding backface-visibility: hidden; to the fixed position elements.
>   That was stopping the paint happening on scroll. So, I had a nice
>   simple solution for my own site but I was annoyed I didn’t understand
>   WHY that worked: I had my suspicions but no actual proof. In these
>   situations I always do the same thing; ask someone way smarter.
>
> … when elements repaint, the dirty rectangle calculation is done per
>   layer. So if an element is on its own layer then it won’t affect
>   anything else. If you promote a fixed header – say – then when content
>   appears at the bottom of the page there is only the new content that
>   needs to be painted. Without the promotion the header needs to be
>   repainted at the top of the page. You might wonder why we don’t
>   automatically promote fixed position elements. The answer is: we do
>   for high DPI screens, but we don’t for low DPI because we lose
>   sub-pixel antialiasing on text, and that’s not something we want to by
>   default. On high DPI screens you can’t tell, so it’s safe there.